# Video for iphone is 480 × 270px be forced fit on iphone screen?

Tags: iphone, video

A video size is dimensions: 480 × 270px. Codecs: H.264, AAC
With subtitles and it fit the width but it leave black gap on iphone screen: top and bottom of screen.

Can a video be forced to fit the screen according to height dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [autoresizesSubviews](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW6) and [contentMode](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW99) View properties of the enclosing control you are having this video in - play with them in the storyboard. For your case, mostly content mode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill should work.

Comment: I'm using HTML5 / cordova 2.1 so that mean I'll need to use p.list settings? Please advise?

Comment: How do I use "UIViewContentModeScaleToFill" in xcode? Is it p.list?

Comment: When you select view in the storyboard, on the right hand side you will see attribute inspector. There, under a section named View, you will find properties like Content Mode, Auto-resizing and all. If you are not using storyboards, please see the Apple links I supplied to set them programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

the aspect ratio for a in iphone 3.x/4.x series is 4:3. any video which is in 4:3 aspect ratio will be played covering fullscreen while playing. You need to be sure that your video is according to the same aspect ratio and in video, there is no black space in original video (by checking it on any desktop's player)

Comment: How can I adjust to 4:3 from 16:9 in xcode 4.5 or p.list? Is that feasible?

Comment: this is smthing that has to be done externally from the application on the video